# ImageView can only load Bitmap when returning from background

Tags: android, image, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I'm using [Universal Image Loader (UIL)](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to do the image loadings in my app.

There are 3 places using UILs

- ListView (success)
- Load image after taking a photo (success)
- Load images from a list of file path (**fail**)

### What I intend to do:

I have a SQLite database to store the BLOB of `ArrayList` of these image files. I can confirm the `ArrayList` is loading correctly with valid image paths.

After loading the image, I'll add each image onto an `ImageView`, and add the `ImageView` to a horizontal `LinearLayout` on the fly.

### Code:

the horizontal `LinearLayout`

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/galleryLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="184dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/image_button_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:maxHeight="184dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

code to display the image:

```
...
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_button);
LinearLayout galleryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.galleryLayout);
...

private void displayImage(String timestamp) {
        DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_action_picture)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_action_warning)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayImageOptions)
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(this))
                .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                .threadPoolSize(5)
                .build();
        ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageloader.destroy();
        imageloader.init(config);

        ArrayList<String> imagePathList = db.getImgPathArray();
        if (imagePathList.size() >= 1) {

            for (int index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                iv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                galleryLayout.addView(iv);
                imageloader.displayImage(imagePathList.get(0), iv);
//                Bitmap bm = imageloader.loadImageSync(imagePathList.get(index), new ImageSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
//                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
//                imageloader.displayImage("db://" + timestamp + "+" + String.valueOf(index), iv, displayImageOptions);
//                imageloader.displayImage("db://" + timestamp + "+" + String.valueOf(0), iv);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code will run without any exceptions or errors, and the `imagePathList` contains correct data if you set break point to have a check. However the none of the `ImageView`s are being added to the `galleryLayout` and no images are displayed.

If I press the home button to put the app `onPause()` and then open it again, I can see the images are well displayed. If you repeat this process multiple times, the images will be added several times.

However, the `displayImage()` is in activity's `onStart()` which should be called only once, not when the activity is resuming from background.

The images are not displayed even if I remove the `for ...` clause and set the `imageLoader` to load just 1 image only.

As I am using the very similar code to deal with the images returned by camera (add the `ImageView` to `LinearLayout` and display it), I cannot figure out why it can't load the images ?

Besides, the images are not loaded after I've added `galleryLayout.invalidate()` after using `imageLoader`. Why?

### UPDATE

Gave another try by loading the `Bitmap` using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` and set the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` via `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` and the image still can't be loaded.

Still the same problem: The image can only be loaded after I press Home to put the app in background and then re-open the app.

Why's that? Are there any problems in my code?

Comment: try changing this ViewGroup.LayoutParams to this LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thx, I just tried your method but still no difference.